# Unity Panel has wrong icons

Tags: unity, compiz, 13.10, icons, panel

I upgraded to 13.10 and installed ubuntu-desktop to try Unity (I have been using KDE). Whenever I log in, the Unity panel icons are wrong - they don't follow the Ubuntu theme and a couple show up as question marks. If I restart unity (by pressing Alt+F2 and running `setsid unity' then the icons are correct.

Just after login:

[image]

After executing `setsid unity`

[image]

I've tried reinstalling Unity, reconfuguring the display manager, executing `unity --reset` and `unity --reset-icons`, and resetting the compiz configuration in dconf, and of course manually resetting the icon themes, but this problem still occurs on every login.

What other configuration files / options are pertinent to Unity? Where else should I look? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by removing the oxygen-gtk theme.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/
```

See [Restore GTK integration after removing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177909/restore-gtk-integration-after-removing-kde)