# Telegram Icon is showing incorrectly on the unity panel

Tags: icons, telegram

Recently I installed Telegram and the panel icon is showing incorrectly like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370115/unity-panel-has-wrong-icons) situation. The answer in that question is not applicable to mine. Can someone help me to fix this kind of problems. The program opens and works correctly.

Comment: have you changed the theme before ??

Comment: Yes I changed the theme before and now I am using the default theme.

Comment: when you change icon on tweak tool is it fix the icon ??

Comment: try **ubuntu mono dark**

Comment: I changed the theme and icons to defaults to see it fixes the problem, but didn't help.

Comment: should I remove the theme?

Comment: i don't think so i just search and trying to install telegram to be accurate

Comment: here is a similar problem on mate if you can try http://simon.aldrich.eu/blog/2016/01/telegram-tray-notification-icon-mate/

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'll try it and tell you the result, I'm on mobile now

Comment: try to open telegram using this command `'/snap/telegram-sergiusens/3/bin/Telegram'`

Comment: this's the regular telegram opening using dash http://i.imgur.com/aKWcUPb.png

Comment: and this after opening with this command http://i.imgur.com/c7xJ4g0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open terminal and run this command:

   `/snap/telegram-sergiusens/3/bin/Telegram`
2. Lock to launcher it will automatically create dash icon called  **Telegram desktop**[image]
3. You can open with this icon it should fix the indicator icon. [image]

Comment: Fortunately this worked. Actually I forgot that This Telegram is a snap package. Sorry. Thank you

Comment: no problem all of us forget :)