# Restore qt integration after removing KDE

Tags: themes, kde, gtk, qt

[Restore GTK integration after removing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177909/restore-gtk-integration-after-removing-kde); this shows how to remove the kde-theme for gtk, and now I want to do the same for qt-applications. I have tried qt4-qtconfig, and it does not work.

Here is an example from a qt application (krita):

[image: kde theme example]

As you can see the button has kde style, and it hadn't before I installed KDE.

So my question is; how do I remove the kde button and menu-style in qt-applications, and restore to the default?

I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is to uninstall the pesky kde icons still used on some qt applications.

```
sudo apt-get purge oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-cursor-theme-extra oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen kde-style-oxyge
```

**Be careful not to uninstall an application you want or need to keep before you accept the changes**

Reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I've already done this, and it doesn't even work for gtk-applications. For gtk-applications you have to do as described in the thread i linked to, and I want to do the same for qt-applications.

Comment: @gustavwiz what is your current gtk theme?

Comment: It is Ambiance.

Comment: @gustavwiz I've tried a couple of gtk themes with krita and noticed the kde icons were static. This is possibly because I have oxygen icons installed. I would try `sudo apt-get purge oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-cursor-theme-extra oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen kde-style-oxygen` then reboot for the changes to take affect.

Comment: **but be carefull not to uninstall something you want or need to keep before accepting the changes**

Comment: @gustavwiz glad to help, here you go