# Ubuntu 14.04 - How to Fix the Ubuntu Appearance

Tags: unity, 14.04, desktop-environments

I have played with XFCE and KDE and after uninstalling them I was left with some problems with my default Ubuntu desktop. I have attached some photos here to show you what I mean.

I would like to reset Ubuntu desktop so that everything looks as it should again.

Thanks!

[image: Broken Top Panel in Ubuntu 14.04]
[image]

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for (duplicate) but I'll post it below for you as well. http://askubuntu.com/questions/491382/restore-qt-integration-after-removing-kde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uninstall all of the plasma packages to get rid of the KDE themes.

```
sudo apt-get purge oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-cursor-theme-extra oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen kde-style-oxyge
```

**be sure to review the list of uninstalled applications before accepting the changes so you don't uninstall something you want or need to keep**