# 17.10 How to reset DE (Gnome) after KDE installation?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, kde5

I'm experiencing several problems in gnome (standard 17.10 installation) after the installation of KDE (just for testing purposes). The main problem is the absence of application icons on the right side of the panel. Where usually icons for teamviewer, dropbox etc. would appear, nothing is displayed after the installation of KDE.
Other problems include different fonts in some applications and different mouse cursors, but those are minor things.

How can i reset gnome back to the default settings?

Comment: Do you want to uninstall kde as well? Usually kde and gnome don't work very well when installed at the same time.

Comment: Yes. KDE was only installed for testing purposes.

Comment: I guess you use the default icons? Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mono`. Also, make sure the correct theme is selected under "Icons" in unity tweak tool (`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal: (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt purge kubuntu-desktop
```

This is based on [Restore qt integration after removing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491382/restore-qt-integration-after-removing-kde):

```
sudo apt-get purge oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-cursor-theme-extra oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen kde-style-oxyge
```

Now reboot

Comment: Well, it worked for the most part. Fonts and cursors are back to normal. The application icons in the panel are not fully restored. It shows teamviewer but not megasync. So it seems there is something else messed up.

Comment: Update: It worked. I'm not sure why, but it seems that it needed more than one restart. I'll accept your answer.