# KDEish theme in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, themes, kde

I installed KDE alongside Ubuntu, but now I want to remove all traces.

As seen here, https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaHMA.png my winows have different icons and a differnet theme. Can anybody help me out? I want to also change the splash screen back  to Ubuntu from Kubuntu.

Comment: can you post the output of `ls -A ~ | grep -v "$(ls ~)"` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen
rm -rf ~/.kde
```

This should uninstall Oxygen for GTK and delete the KDE preferences directory in your home folder.

Source: [Restore GTK integration after removing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177909/restore-gtk-integration-after-removing-kde/278081#278081)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what KDE package you installed you'll want to use apt-gets purge switch.

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge kde-full
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge kde-plasma-desktop
```

If you've already uninstalled it and simply want to correct your theme go to the settings manager and select the Radiance Theme. That should return your system to the pre-KDE state.

Comment: Didn't work. I purged those, each one, but they all were already removed.

Comment: Have you tried going into the settings manager to change the theme?

Comment: Go to System Setting, then click on Appearance. Then on the bottom of the screen you should be able to select Radiance or Ambiance from the Theme selection towards the bottom.